# Parent flex doesn't shrink when using flex-basis and long text in child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a parent flex that has a child which uses a flex-basis to wrap some text. I'd like for the parent to shrink to only the content of the child, but it instead takes up as much space as the text would take had it not wrapped.

```css
.parent-flex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child-flex {
  flex: 0 1 442px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-flex">
  <div class="child-flex">
    text lots and lots of text that goes on for a little while and wraps, ideally there should be no visible blue since the parent should fit the content exactly
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like for the above demo to show no blue at all. What can I do to shrink the parent-flex to the child-flex's current size?

Comment: If you are using a fixed flex-basis, of course it would wrap after taking that space.

Comment: I want the text to wrap when it reaches the flex-basis so that's working correctly. What's not working is that the parent-flex sets its size with little regard for the child's flex-basis, so even though the text is wrapping the parent extends across the full screen.

Comment: Yes, but the parent container respects its parent container i.e. body and not the child element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution I think is to use a max width, as it looks like you're fighting with the flexbox layout mode. You can slap a width of max content on the parent to stop it growing but I really don't see why when you can remove the background color.

```css
.parent-flex {
  width: max-content;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child-flex {
  max-width: 442px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-flex">
  <div class="child-flex">
    text lots and lots of text that goes on for a little while and wraps, ideally there should be no visible blue since the parent should fit the content exactly
  </div>
</div>
```